# PyCharm @overload Operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, overloading, typing

I'm trying to use the `@overload` decorator from the `typing` library in PyCharm and I'm getting warnings, but the code runs fine. Am I using the operator wrong, or is PyCharm just issuing warnings incorrectly?

I'm using PyCharm Community 2016.3.2 and Python 3.5.2.

```python
from typing import Optional, List, overload


@overload
def hello_world(message: str) -> str:
    pass

# Warning: Redeclared 'hello_world' usage defined above without usage
def hello_world(message: str, second_message: Optional[str] = None) -> List[str]:
    if second_message is None:
        # Warning: Expected type 'List[str]', got 'str' instead
        return message
    else:
        return [
            message,
            second_message
        ]


def count_single_message(message: str) -> int:
    return len(message)


def count_multiple_message(messages: List[str]) -> int:
    total = 0
    for message in messages:
        total += len(message)

    return total


print(
    count_single_message(
        # Warning: Expected type 'List[str]', got 'str' instead
        hello_world('hello world')))
print(
    count_multiple_message(
        hello_world('hello world', 'how are you?')))
```

Update: A bug has been filed about this matter: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22971.

Comment: *What* warnings…?

Comment: Again, what warnings do you get? I get just redefinition and type warnings with the above code put in PC.

Comment: @linusg, That is all I get, just the redefinition and type warnings. The code runs fine. I'm just asking about PyCharm warnings, not Python warnings, not code running issues. I'm trying to sort out if I'm doing it wrong, or PyCharm is.

Comment: I get it. In my experiency, PyCharm is somewhat outdated with such things, so I guess it's not your fault.

Comment: @linusg What IDE do you think might support such things?

Comment: `typing.overload` could be used only in stubs. Why did you put first `hello_world` here? It's OK to have only second one.

Comment: A bug has been filed about this matter: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22971. Feel free to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded functions should have at least 2 overload signatures and 1 implementation with no type hints. I believe that is a requirement for various type checkers (notably mypy).

This code gets rid of the two `Expected type 'List[str]', got 'str' instead` warnings, I didn't have the `Redeclared 'hello_world' usage` warning.

```
@overload
def hello_world(message: str) -> str:
    ...

@overload
def hello_world(message: str, second_message: str) -> List[str]:
    ...

def hello_world(message, second_message=None):
    if second_message is None:
        return message
    else:
        return [
            message,
            second_message
        ]
```

This is with Pycharm 2019.2.5 which is more recent, but I had the same `Expected type` warnings so it probably doesn't matter.